# Are Kusto ingestion transactions atomic in terms of extents?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I would like know if kusto ingestion transactions are guaranteed to be atomic in terms of extents? So lets say I have a process that is periodically pushing data to some kusto table (e.g. using .append) & each time pushing to a different extent tag (so as to make sure that in each ingestion the data goes to different extent id) , is there a guarantee that all the records in a given extent appear in the table at the same time -- so either the whole extent is visible for anyone querying that table or none of the records are available. So basically atomicity in terms of extents -- trying to make sure that under no circumstances partially written extents are exposed to any queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For an `.append` command:**

1. The added extent(s), if there are any, are committed in a single transaction, upon successful completion of the command.
2. Upon failure in data ingestion (e.g., there was a transient storage failure), new extent(s) will not be added.
3. Upon failure in data ingestion, when the `extend_schema` option is set to `true`, the target table will still have its schema extended.
4. There is no case where not all created extent(s) are committed to the table - either all are committed, or none are.

**For a `.set-or-append` command:**

1. If the table is created by the command (i.e., it did not already exist), it is committed regardless of the sequential data ingestion phase.
2. The added extent(s), if there are any, are committed in a single transaction, upon successful completion of the command.
3. Upon failure in data ingestion (e.g., there was a transient storage failure), new extent(s) will not be added, but the table will remain in the database.
4. Upon failure in data ingestion, when the `extend_schema` option is set to `true`, the target table will still have its schema extended.
5. There is no case where not all created extent(s) are committed to the table - either all are committed, or none are.